# Navigation component, nested graph, startDestination

Tags: android, navigation, androidx, back-stack

Recently I've updated the `navigation component` to **2.3.2** and then, when I navigate to a fragment in a nested graph via DeepLink everything is ok; But when `popBackStack`, the start destination is poped with it too.
Does anyone face a similar problem?

Comment: I ran into the same problem last week. if you solved this, please update your answer so I can use it too. thanks.